# C Pointer/reference to array of structures from within function

Tags: c, arrays, arduino, fastled

I got a problem with making a custom function on top of the [FastLed](https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED) library for Arduino.

The array of leds, [structures called CRGB](https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/blob/master/pixeltypes.h#L70) needs to be altered from inside the function `drawGradient` to set the colors of the LEDs.

There must be something wrong with the pointers, references, parameters of the functions but I can't seem to figure out how to do it right. How to properly use the pointers/references for this piece of code?

**Lines of interest**

```
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

void loop() {
    drawGradient(&leds, 4, 0, CRGB::White, CRGB::Lime);
}

void drawGradient(struct CRGB leds[], unsigned int from, unsigned int to, struct CRGB fromColor, struct CRGB toColor) {
    leds[j] = pickFromGradient(fromColor, fromColor, position);
}
```

**Full code**

```
#include "FastLED.h"

#define NUM_LEDS 18

#define DATA_PIN 7

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, DATA_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
}

void loop() {
  leds[4] = CRGB::Red;
  FastLED.show();

  delay(1000);

  drawGradient(&leds, 4, 0, CRGB::White, CRGB::Lime);
  drawGradient(&leds, 4, 8, CRGB::White, CRGB::Lime);
  drawGradient(&leds, 13, 9, CRGB::White, CRGB::Lime);
  drawGradient(&leds, 13, 17, CRGB::White, CRGB::Lime);

  FastLED.show();

  while(1); // Save energy :-)
}

void drawGradient(struct CRGB leds[], unsigned int from, unsigned int to, struct CRGB fromColor, struct CRGB toColor) {
  unsigned int barLength = abs(to - from) + 1;
  int rangePerPixel = 255/barLength;

  for(int i = 0; i <= barLength; i++) {
    int j = 0;
    if(from < to) {
      j = from + i;
    } else {
      j = max(from, to) - i;
    }

    float position = i / barLength;

    leds[j] = pickFromGradient(fromColor, toColor, position);
  }
}

struct CRGB pickFromGradient(struct CRGB fromColor, struct CRGB toColor, float position) {
  struct CRGB newColor;

  uint8_t r = fromColor.r + position * (toColor.r - fromColor.r);
  uint8_t g = fromColor.g + position * (toColor.g - fromColor.g);
  uint8_t b = fromColor.b + position * (toColor.b - fromColor.b);

  newColor.setRGB(r, g, b);

  return newColor;
}
```

Comment: My C is a bit rusty, but shouldn't you be calling as `drawGradient( leds, ... )` since C arrays are passed as pointers to the first element (IIRC)?

Comment: You use `pickFromGradient(fromColor, fromColor, position)` but it looks like it must be `pickFromGradient(fromColor, toColor, position)`.

Comment: That's a good one iKiWiXz! Fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you function signature:

```
  void drawGradient(struct CRGB leds[], unsigned int from, unsigned int to, struct CRGB fromColor, struct CRGB toColor)
```

To

```
void drawGradient(struct CRGB *leds, unsigned int from, unsigned int to, struct CRGB fromColor, struct CRGB toColor)
```

And call the function drawGradient in the following way:

```
  drawGradient(leds, 4, 0, CRGB::White, CRGB::Lime);
```

leds itself is the pointer of the array of CRGB structure. The &leds refers to the address of the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

pickFromGradient is being called with the same colors:

```
leds[j] = pickFromGradient(fromColor, fromColor, position);
```

should be:

```
leds[j] = pickFromGradient(fromColor, toColor, position);
```

Comment: Oh, just missed that. I would have it placed as a comment if I could. :)